# Debian: cannot install packages

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

Some time ago I had an old Debian system on my VPS. Probably it was Lenny. In /etc/apt/sources.list it was `stable` so I don't really know what it was. So I've decided to upgrade it. My steps were:

- replacing `stable` with `squeeze` (since I thought it was `Lenny`)
- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade

It updated some packages but not too much as usual when version upgrades.
So after that I've tried to upgrade to `Wheezy` in same way and then to `Jessie`. But there was some error with `udev` and kernel so I've removed `udev`. Accidentally it also removed my current kernel 2.6.32. So I decided to downgrade to `Wheezy`. Currently my sources.list is:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Also all apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade were executed but nothing happened. It said:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now I cannot install packages:

```
apt-get install ***
Package *** is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

But these packages have to be here. For example, I try to install [mc](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mc) package:

```
aptitude show mc
No current or candidate version found for mc
Package: mc
State: not installed
Version: 3:4.8.3-10
Priority: optional
Section: utils
```

So now my system works but I cannot install any package and cannot do anything. If suddenly my VPS will reboot I get non-working brick.

Yes, I know I've make tons of mistakes but how can I get it work? I prefer to stay with `Wheezy`. Any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: Ask your hosting company to reinstall your VPS

Comment: Ah, this answer is preferable in Windows section, not Unix :) Sure, I know about this option bit there are too many files over the system, I just cannot do that. Also I think that have to be some way to repair my system without reinstall it.

Comment: Not without a package manager.  `apt-get` is crucial and you've hosed it.

Comment: `stable` always tracks whatever is considered the stable release at the moment (or whenever you last updated your packages). If you had just done `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, you would have moved to Jessie. Also, reverting to an older release isn't guaranteed to work by any measure.

Comment: Considering you still have `aptitude`, can you run `aptitude update` and see the output?

Comment: A VPS is never meant to be upgraded via a customer update... You can add tools and scripts, but major upgrades should be done by the hosting provider so that things like this don't happen. If aptitude doesn't work your only option is to reinstall.

Comment: Both aptitude and apt-get work without problem. But there is some crap that block it. It looks that it's some version misunderstanding. `aptitude update` updates all source as I see. But `apt-get upgrade` says: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. And so if I try to install any package it say: `Package *** is not available, but is referred to by another package`

Comment: I don't quite understand what state your system is in. Please post the output of `apt-cache policy; apt-cache policy udev`. Making APT work again is probably not that difficult but in the meantime you might work to manually download the `.deb` file for the wheezy kernel (and udev and any other critical package) and install them with `dpkg`.

Comment: Thanks for all for the help! I've asked my hoster to reinstall the system as easy and fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can see is to install a Wheezy system in a VM (you could use VirtualBox), trying to get the same package list as your VPS (use `dpkg --get-selections` to generate it)

Then you should copy every package in */var/cache/apt/*deb* from your VM to your VPS and, finally, use `dpkg -i *deb` to install them.

I cannot guarantee it will work but I would try it before restoring/formatting my VPS.

Comment: Use debootstrap and install them in a chroot.